# CSS LESS Placeholder Mixin

Tags: css, less, mixins

I want to create a placeholder mixin as follows.  However, this fails to compile in LESS version 1.7.0.

```
.placeholder(...) {
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder: @arguments;
    :-moz-placeholder: @arguments;
    ::-moz-placeholder: @arguments;
    :-ms-input-placeholder: @arguments;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile because it tries to generate malformed CSS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Input placeholders are selectors, not properties, and so their CSS syntax is `placeholder { ... }`, not `placeholder: ...` which you are trying to generate.

If you fix that:

```
.placeholder(...) {
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {border:@arguments}
    ::-moz-placeholder {border:@arguments}
    :-ms-input-placeholder {border:@arguments}
}
```

It will compile, and when you call it:

```
.placeholder(solid; 1px; blue;);
```

it will generate this CSS:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  border: solid 1px #0000ff;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  border: solid 1px #0000ff;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  border: solid 1px #0000ff;
}
```

(I just included `border:` as an example of a generic CSS property, independent of its actual effect on an input object)

Comment: This works and clarifies the use of the @arguments parameter.  This helped get me to my final mixin that allows for any placeholder rules.

Answer (score 71):

Mixin allows for any placeholder css rules.

```
.placeholder(@rules) {

    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        @rules();
    }
    &:-moz-placeholder {
        @rules();
    }
    &::-moz-placeholder {
        @rules();
    }
    &:-ms-input-placeholder {
        @rules();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
.placeholder({
    color: #0000FF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
});
```

Comment: which LESS version are you using - it does not compile for me

Comment: works for me with `lessc -v` 2.0.0. Ampersand and passed-in rules makes this way more useful than the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the nice syntax! What purpose do the parens serve after `@rules()`? I thought parens were only used for parametric mixins?

Comment: Does `[placeholder](@rules) { ... }`  work as well? I would like to omit the redundant class.

Comment: why the two `moz-placeholders`?

Comment: @GianPaJ One is for firefox 4-18 (the one with a single colon) and the other with two colons is for firefox 19+.

Comment: I get a syntax error when trying to compile this:  
`SyntaxError: Rulesets cannot be evaluated on a property`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the curly brackets around the placeholder selectors.

The styles should be as follows:

```
.placeholder(@color) {
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: @color;
    }
    :-moz-placeholder {
        color: @color;
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder {
      color: @color;
    }
}
```